# Download file broken while pipe file to response in express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to download file from my server to users, but files are all broken while pipe file to response using following code, and the size of downloaded file is much bigger than the size of original file.

```
fs.stat('./client/public/output.zip',function (err,stat) {
    var stream=fs.createReadStream('./client/public/output.zip');
    response.setHeader('Content-Type','object');
    response.setHeader('Content-Length',stat.size);
    response.setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename=output.zip');
    response.writeHead(200);
    stream.pipe(response); })
```

I also tried response.download(),but it doesn't work

the file size is about 6MB, and my os is OSX

Comment: I just found it's ok when I using a download tool or using IE while downloading, but it it get wrong using Chrome, Safari and Edge

Comment: I tried your code, it works fine with Iron (a Chromium fork) and Edge. Did you try without setting any header nor fs.stat? Only `stream.pipe(response);`.

Comment: @S.D. I copy-pasted OP's code and it worked as it is.

Comment: @ShanShan I have tried only `stream.pipe(response)`, but it doesn't work

Comment: Weird, can you add nodejs and express version in your post?

Comment: @S.D. I moved `response.writeHead(200);`  in front of `response.setHeader('Content-Type','object');` and an error occurred `Can\'t set headers after they are sent.`

Comment: @ShanShan node 5.9.1 and  Express 4.13.4

Comment: also got wrong when I config `use static` and put the file in a static resource folder

Answer (score 0):

I just find the reason, cause I configured `connect-livereload`, you can find the issue here 
https://github.com/intesso/connect-livereload/issues/39